# Typescript casting

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I make my typescript compiler happy without changing the interface and typeof argument I'm receiving in function test.

Error in function test:-

> "Property 'method2' does not exist on type 'xyz'. Did you mean
>   'method1'?"

```js
interface xyz { 
    method1(): string;
}

class abc implements xyz { 
    method1() { 
        return "abc";
    }
    method2() { 
        return "new method";
    }
}

function test(arg: xyz) {
    alert(arg.method2());
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20xyz%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20abc%20implements%20xyz%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22abc%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method2()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22new%20method%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(arg%3A%20xyz)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(arg.method2())%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Can you explain what the compiler is not happy about?

Comment: only option is adding `method2` as a part of interface

Comment: What is your problem? What's the compiler error? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you open the link I have shared you'll get to know. 
Copiler is throwing this error:-
"Property 'method2' does not exist on type 'xyz'. Did you mean 'method1'?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through documents, got to know about Type assertions, which helped me to compile that small piece of code successfully.

```
function test(arg: xyz) {
   var arg2 = <abc>arg; 
   alert(arg2.method2());
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't.

Why ?

To make your code to pass compiler you need either add the `method2` into the interface `xyz` or change the type parameter to accept the type `abc`. But you don't want neither.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type guard to change the type that is seen at the compiler when you want to access the other fields:

```
function isAbc(arg: xyz | abc): arg is abc {
    return (<abc>arg).method2 !== undefined;
}

function test(arg: xyz) {
    if (isAbc(arg)) {
        // here the type of `arg` is `abc`
        alert(arg.method2());
    }
}
```